# A question regarding a cubic polynomial.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My Algebra book has the following question:

> Prove that the cubic equation $x^3-3px-2q=0$ is satisfied by $x=s+t$ only if $st=p$ and $s^3+t^3=2q$.

Let us take the equation. $x^3-3x+2=0$. Here $p=1$ and $q=-1$.

It is satisfied by $x=1$. We can express $x$ as $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$, where $s=t=\frac{1}{2}$. Clearly $\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2}=4\neq 1$. Hence, $st\neq p$. Is this not a contradiction?

Comment: Possible explanation (assuming that books are never wrong:) ): "only if" means that it is a suffecient conditions. If you find $s,t$ that satisfy the conditios about $p,q$ then $x=s+t$ solves the equation. If the expression was "if and only if" that would mean that these are the only $x$'s, so in that case you would have a contradiction. Now you do not.

Comment: The book's wording (as given above) is incorrect. The statement "$P$ only if $Q$" means "$P$ implies $Q$", and that is not true as you have shown. Personally, I hate the use of "only if" and wish people would avoid it and write in a more straightforward manner, such as "If $P,$ then $Q$" where it is clear at a glance what the implication is and the implication is written in the same order as its mathematical symbolization "$P \implies Q$".

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro you are right, of course - if the book says "only if" then it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Algebra book interprets "only if" as "if", this is asking to show that if $p = st$ and $2q = s^3 + t^3$, then the cubic polynomial $x^3 - 3px - 2q$ has a root (a zero) at $x = s+t$.

To prove this, let's first plug $p = st$ and $2q = s^3 + t^3$ into the cubic polynomial. This should give us:
$$x^3 - 3stx + s^3 + t^3$$
Now, to find the possible roots of this polynomial, we use the Rational Root Test, which says that the possible roots of a polynomial $Ax^n + \cdots + Bx + C$ are of the form $x = \frac{c}{a}$, where $c$ is a factor of $C$ (the constant term), and $a$ is a factor of $A$ (the leading coefficient).

From here, notice that our constant term is $s^3 + t^3$. Since this is a sum of cubes, it can be factored as $(s+t)(s^2 - st + t^2)$. Our leading coefficient is $1$ since we have $x^3$ as our leading term. So, our choices for $c$ and $a$ are
$$c = s+t \enspace \mbox {or} \enspace s^2 - st + t^2,$$
$$ a = 1 \enspace \mbox{or} \enspace -1.$$

You can finish this off by using Rational Root Test.

Answer (score 0):

To follow through stefano's comment, take the equation $x^3-3x+2$ with $p=1, q=-1$ and compute the values of $s$ and $t$ which work.

We have $st=1$ whence $s^3t^3=1$ and $s^3+t^3=-1$

This means that $s^3, t^3$ are the roots of $y^2+y+1=0$ i.e. $$s^3,t^3=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{-3}}{2}$$ and $s,t$ are appropriate cube roots. So the two numbers $s,t$ are not arbitrary numbers which sum to $x$, but in fact are highly constrained. The point is that such constrained $s$ and $t$ can be found by solving a quadratic equation - which we know how to do, and hence we can solve the cubic.

I am sure the details of all this are contained in your book.

The "only if" comment you have quoted suggests that the constraints are inherent in the equation, and that is wrong. The constraints for $s,t$ in terms of $p,q$ are carefully chosen to make the method work, and that was the insight of those who first solved the cubic in this way - it should be "if".